# Error:not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have this signup page and when i am submitting the form i am getting this error:not all arguments converted during string formatting

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
email = StringField('Email address')
password = PasswordField('password')
name = StringField('Name')

@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
try:
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = form.email.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt((str(form.password.data)))
        con = connection()
        cur=con.cursor()
        x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (%s)",(thwart(email)))
        if int(x) > 0:
            return render_template('register.html',form=form)
        else:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO user (username,password,name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);",(thwart(email),thwart(password),thwart(name),))
            con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

Comment: is the comma a typo `thwart(name),))`?

Comment: @Jens I don't think it is, I had to put this weird `thwart(name),)` last time I used `cursor.execute`

Comment: @pwnsauce The `,` is necessary when creating one-tuples. While not a typo, it is not needed when creating a tuple with more than one value.

Comment: hanks for your help as i am new into this i could really use your help after fixing this error .. now i am getting this error: global name 'name' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

`x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (%s)",(thwart(email)))`

The second argument of `execute` should be a tuple, you are missing a `,`:

`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = (%s)",(thwart(email),))`

I guess that you also don't need the `()` around the `%s` but it depends on how your table actually looks like.

Further clarification:

`('str')` will evaluate to the string `'str'`, not to a tuple containing it.

In order to create a one-tuple, you must include a comma: `('str',)`.

Comment: thanks for your help as i am new into this i could really use your help
after fixing this error ..
now i am getting this error: global name 'name' is not defined